# Pymongo check if field exists in document

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a posts document. I'd like to add comments to this document as embedded. Some of the documents doesn't have comments field.

```
{
    "_id" : 6,
    "title" : "Emacs tutorial",
    "updatedate" : ISODate("2017-10-18T19:05:08.555Z"),
    "content" : "Welcome to Emacs tutorial\n",
    "comments" : {
        "date" : "2016-04-20",
        "content" : "first comment",
        "_id" : 122
    }
}
```

What I'd like to do is check whether current document includes 'comments' field.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
document = mongo.db.posts

result = document.find(
    { '_id' : int(number) },
    { "comments": { '$exists': True, '$ne': False } })

print(result)

if result:
    print ('I find the comments field')
else:
    print ('I shouldn't find')
```

But I recognized that printing the result returns a pymongo.cursor.Cursor object.

Comment: A "query" is a **single** document. You are splitting each property into separate documents, which is **wrong**. `document.find( { '_id' : int(number) , "comments": { '$exists': True, '$ne': False } })`. So one dict/document only. Additional arguments mean something else entirely and are not the "query". Read the documentation. [`.find()`](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find). Also you want `.find_one()` for just one document. Otherwise it's a "cursor" that gets returned.

Comment: I suppose the main issue was using `.find_one()`. Thanks..